# Jenkins token expansion doesn't accept parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image: Example triggered build]

I want to pass a version label like `master.104.a1b2c3d` down to a triggered build. Using `${GIT_BRANCH}` in its default shape I get `origin/master` instead of `master`, which I don't want. The [Token Macro plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin) suggests I should be able to add parameters (and [the code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitBranchTokenMacro.java) suggests a `fullName` parameter exists) so I need to be able to apply these parameters to manipulate the output.

**Expected:**

```
target=c42cccac2cc…
versionLabel=master.104.c42ccca
```

**Observed:**

```
target=c42cccac2cc…
versionLabel=${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false}.104.${GIT_REVISION,length=7}
```

Perhaps I'm using the parameters incorrectly? Even the example from the documentation doesn't work here, but any expansion without parameters goes just fine.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this. I am looking to do the same kind of thing.

Comment: Sadly, I did not. I ended up hard-coding the branch names in parameters passed from above and leaving the SHA in long form. :(

Answer (score 0):

The additional parameters won't work everywhere in jenkins config. See [JENKINS-25465](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25465) for details.